# Show that a vector field $F$ is gradient of some potential $\varphi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This problem is actually from Apostol's Calculus 2:

A radial or "central" force field $F$ in the plane can be written in the form $F(x,y)= f(\|r\|)r$, where $r=(x,y)$. Show that such a force field is conservative.

My solution attempt:

I tried to show that the vector field $F$ is continuous. Since $F(x,y) = (x.f(\|r\|),y.f(\|r\|)$, it follows that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are linear. Hence, since linear functions are continuous, we have that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are continuous. So recalling the second fundamental theorem of line integrals we can interpretate $F$ as a gradient of a potential $\varphi%$, which proves that $F$ is conservative.

Is it correct? Is it only necessary to show that $F$ has continuous componentes? Do i have to suppose that $F$ is gradient of some fucntion?

Comment: $x.f(\|r\|) = x.f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ is usually not linear, and the same with $y.f(\|r\|)$. For instance, the Newtonian model for the gravitational field around an object of mass $M$ is $\frac{GM}{\|r\|^2}\cdot r$, where $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, and this is well-known to be non-linear but still conservative.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how do i prove that $F$ is conservative without previous knowledge of physics? Do i have to show that taking $\alpha$ and $\beta$, two different piecewise smooth paths, the line integral is independent of them?

Or just showing that the vector field $F$ is continuous is sufficient?

Comment: There are many continuous, non-conservative fields, so that is absolutely not sufficient. You could take the two paths approach, but if possible (I haven't tried) I would amend that with the following: Show that the curl of the field is zero (except possibly at the origin). Then the only thing you have left to prove for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is that which side of the origin they go doesn't matter. Try to look up how the curl operator looks when expressed in polar coordinates, though, because it looks like that might be easier in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\varphi(x,y)= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and  $f(||r||)=1/||r||$. Hence we have that $\nabla \varphi = (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$. Since we defined $f(||r||)=1/||r||$, it follows  that $\nabla \varphi = (x.f(||r||), y.f(||r||)) = F(x,y)$, proving that $F$ is conservative, by definition.