# Check whether this vector field is radial

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

My textbook says the following vector field is radial. How shall I check it?
$F(x,y)=(x^2,xy)$

Let us take three different radius of same magnitude and check whether the magnitude of vector at these points (equidistant from the centre) are same.

Points $(10,0),(6,8),(0,10)$ are equidistant from the centre. The vectors at these points are $(100,0),(36,48),(0,0)$. But their magnitudes are not same. Then how can this be a radial vector field?

Comment: The definition of a radial vector field is not that it has the same norm at points equidistant from the origin, but that it’s always parallel to the displacement vector from the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector field $F(x,y)$ is *radial* if each vector in the field points either towards or away from the origin that is iff  is $F(x,y)$ is proportional to the position vector $(x,y)$.

In your case
$F(x,y)=x(x,y)$. It is zero along the line $x=0$ and it points away from the origin elsewhere. Note that this vector field is not conservative in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because for $y\not=0$,
$$y=\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} \not=\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}=0.$$

Comment: I understand it. But what is a vector field originating from a center and have equal values at points equidistant from center and is radial called?. Is such a vector field necessarily conservative?

Comment: In that case yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993218/show-that-a-vector-field-f-is-gradient-of-some-potential-varphi